# How to properly delete a PHP session?

Tags: php, session

I previously used these three lines to delete a session:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
session_destroy();
```

Does `session_destroy()` close the session, or do I have to close it manually?

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION = array();
session_write_close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are destroying the session then there isn't really a need to session_write_close(), as in the manual it does the following:

> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time.

Answer (score 6):

`session_destroy` delete the session's data in the media (file, database, etc) where is stored, but doesn't delete the `$_SESSION` array or the cookies, you have to do it manually, that includes the `PHPSESSID` cookie.

I normally delete the sessions with something like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val)
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $val)
    setcookie($key, '', 1);
session_destroy();
```

BTW when you call `session_regenerate_id()` the session's file is copied to the new file but the old one isn't deleted, if you want to delete the old data session's file (probably you want) you must specify it with `session_regenerate_id(TRUE)`.

Comment: It sounds a bit dangerous to delete every cookie, e.g. if you use cookies for other web applications at the current domain. You just need to delete the cookie holding the session: `setcookie(session_name(), '', 0); unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);`